# Copy a folder with many folders on Windows 8 not possible due to too long names

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have copied a folder with many subfolders into

```
C:\test
```

Windows explorer is saying now that some folder names make the directory path too long.

What can I do against this? I really can not change the source folders names and I have to copy those folders!

I use Windows 8.1 Pro

The problem is NOT that a single folder name is too long. 
The problem IS that the whole directory path seems to be too long.

Comment: this has been answered so many times, please search

Comment: While I drafted this question the links showing up did not led me to an useful answer.

Comment: try one of these 108 results: http://superuser.com/search?q=folder+name+too+long

Comment: This: http://superuser.com/questions/375577/extracting-file-with-too-long-of-a-name is the first or your search links and its about ubuntu... I search for a concrete Windows problem "Windows 8 folder name too long" I get 10 results and none helps! Have you checked quickly the 108 results? They all talk NOT about my problem!

Comment: Oh well if the first result doesn't work then I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: As I said before I have also checked the other links... The only solution seems to use this tool: http://www.ghisler.com/index.htm which uses the NT limitation with 32000 chars for a dir path.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/708365/file-name-too-long-for-just-windows-explorer http://superuser.com/questions/775118/the-file-names-would-be-too-long-for-the-destination-folders-but-i-cant-edit http://superuser.com/questions/705417/in-windows-7-how-do-i-get-around-the-the-file-names-would-be-too-long-for-th

Comment: Thanks for the links. Not using the Windows Shell like the command line seems to be a solution. I did an XCopy on the main folder and I got at least no errors/warnings/questions during copying the data. And the application starts so I guess the CMD helped.